# TomEE in Eclipse always uses HSQL Database Engine instead of defined in persistence.xml (EclipseLink)

Tags: maven, jpa, eclipselink, hsqldb

I am using:

TomEE 7.0 + EclipseLink + Vaadin (+ Vaadin JPA) + Maven

When I am running my app on server inside the Eclipse, TomEE ignores my DB params defined in `persistence.xml`. It always uses build-in HSQL Database Engine even if i define `eclipselink.target-database` property

*persistence.xml*:

```
 <persistence-unit name="OFFERTER_JPA"
    transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>OFFERTER_DS</non-jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.PostgreSQLPlatform"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/oferter" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="oferter" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="oferter" />
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="ALL" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

The result on console shows that TomEE **reads the params** and tries to create connection but **as a result connects to HSQL** instead of PostgreSQL:

```css
[EL Info]: 2015-06-22 14:54:23.491--ServerSession(1776533395)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-9,5,main])--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070
[EL Config]: 2015-06-22 14:54:23.501--ServerSession(1776533395)--Connection(1077694737)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-9,5,main])--connecting(DatabaseLogin(
    platform=>PostgreSQLPlatform
    user name=> "oferter"
    connector=>JNDIConnector datasource name=>null
))
cze 22, 2015 2:54:23 PM org.hsqldb.persist.Logger logInfoEvent
INFO: checkpointClose start
cze 22, 2015 2:54:24 PM org.hsqldb.persist.Logger logInfoEvent
INFO: checkpointClose end
[EL Config]: 2015-06-22 14:54:24.073--ServerSession(1776533395)--Connection(2047991763)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-9,5,main])--Connected: jdbc:hsqldb:file:C:\Programowanie\workspace\java\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\data\hsqldb\hsqldb
    User: SA
    Database: HSQL Database Engine  Version: 2.3.2
    Driver: HSQL Database Engine Driver  Version: 2.3.2
[EL Finest]: 2015-06-22 14:54:24.073--ServerSession(1776533395)--Connection(933531057)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-9,5,main])--Connection acquired from connection pool [read].
[EL Finest]: 2015-06-22 14:54:24.074--ServerSession(1776533395)--Connection(933531057)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-9,5,main])--Connection released to connection pool [read].
```

What is strange. **If I export the application to standalone .WAR** using `Export -> WAR file` from Eclipse and deploy it by hand on the same TomEE instance, **it behaves correctly and connects to PostgreSQL**

Similar problem is described here:

[The same problem description - no solution](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/458074/)

Comment: You have a <non-jta-data-source>OFFERTER_DS</non-jta-data-source> defined - what is it pointing at?  Try removing it and then only your javax.persistence.jdbc setting will be used.

Comment: Removing <non-jta-data-source> causes: `Cannot use an EntityTransaction while using JTA.`Exception because RESOURCE_LOCAL transaction type is used. It also does not remove the problem unfortunately.

Comment: Then you are using something that is reconfiguring your persistence unit, as you have not specified this Persistence unit to use JTA.  How are your entityManagers obtained?

Comment: But i think my configuration of persistence unit is correct because when i export it as .war and doploy by hand it works as expected. The problem occurs only if I use `Run As -> Run on Server` in Eclipse. PE is obtained by Vaadin JPA: `JPAContainer<UserBE> persons =
      JPAContainerFactory.make(UserBE.class, "OFFERTER_JPA");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create /WEB-INF/resources.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tomee>

  <Resource id="myDS" type="DataSource">
    JdbcDriver  = org.postgresql.Driver
    JdbcUrl = jdbc:postgresql://112.216.148.236:5432/ncore
    UserName  =  xxx
    Password  = xxx
</Resource>
</tomee>
```

and then try

Comment: I Have it but....after your comment i realized that I didnt place `<Resource>` inside `<tomee></tomee>`. **Now it works! Thanks!** That was the case!